# How to rotate the center of the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When rotating the screen, like a blender
I want to rotate the screen to a point in the center of the screen.
However, since the center of the screen, it is a 2d coordinate, so even if the screen center vector comes out, the corresponding point does not come out. Even though there is a vector that the camera shoots in a straight line, the point cannot be accurately known, so I do not know what center point zpos to rotate the screen based on.

[image: blender rotate]

I don't know how to specify the z-axis of the center coordinate of the screen so that it moves through the center of the screen like a blender.
Is the grid tile based on the z-axis?

```
void setRotInsideOtherWay(Vector3 ve3)
    {
        Debug.Log(CameraManager.S.LookPos);
        //1 this way is not work
        //2 Lookpos is tranform.foward
        //mCamParent.transform.Rotate(ve3);
        //mCamParent.transform.LookAt(CameraManager.S.LookPos);

        //
        Camera.main.transform.RotateAround(point , ve3,10f);
      

    }
```

edit image error sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  [SerializeField, Range(0.0f, 1.0f)]
    float lerpRate;
    float xRotation;
    float yRotation;

    float xMovement;
    float yMovement;

    UndoRedo undoRedo;

    //CamVectorSaver camVectorSaver;
   // RecordStarter recordStarter;

    [Header("Set in inspector")]

    public GameObject replyObj;

    public static event MouseMoved MouseMoved;

   
    private static void OnMouseMoved(float xmovement, float ymovement)
    {
        MouseMoved handler = MouseMoved;
        if (handler != null) handler(xmovement, ymovement);
    }
    private void Rotate(float xMovement, float yMovement)
    {
        xRotation += xMovement;
        yRotation += yMovement;
    }
    
    void Start()
    {
        undoRedo = ObjectManager.S.gameObject.GetComponent<UndoRedo>();
        
      //  recordStarter = replyObj.GetComponent<RecordStarter>();
        //camVectorSaver = this.GetComponent<CamVectorSaver>();
        MouseMoved += Rotate;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (!SubCamManager.S.checkInOut)
            return;
        if (SubCamManager.S.mouseClickMode == MouseClickMode.Drawline
            && SubCamManager.S.mouseClickMode == MouseClickMode.Lasootool)
            return;
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)||Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            return;
        //if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2) && recordStarter.booRecordOn)
        //{
        //  //  camVectorSaver.EnableScript(false);
        //    recordStarter.RecordTime();
        //}
        InvokeActionOnInput();
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2)||Input.GetButton("Horizontal")
            || Input.GetButton("Vertical") )
        {
            xRotation = Mathf.Lerp(xRotation, 0, lerpRate);
            yRotation = Mathf.Lerp(yRotation, 0, lerpRate);
           
            //Gimballock 
            //transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(-yRotation, xRotation, 0);
            
            Quaternion yRot = Quaternion.Euler(0f, xRotation, 0f);
            Quaternion xRot = Quaternion.Euler(-yRotation, 0f, 0f);

            transform.rotation = yRot * transform.rotation * xRot;
        }
       
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        MouseMoved += Rotate;
    }

    private void InvokeActionOnInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
        {
            xMovement = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            yMovement = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
            OnMouseMoved(xMovement, yMovement);
        }
        //키보드 사용 하는 부분
        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
        {
            xMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 0.7f;

            OnMouseMoved(xMovement, 0);
        }
      
        if (Input.GetButton("Vertical"))
        {
            yMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*0.7f;

            OnMouseMoved(0, yMovement);
        }
    }
```